# Babel, npm, Polyfill and Object.assign config

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am currently trying to config babel for use with a Vue project and I am experiencing a Javascript error `The object does not support the property or method 'assign'` in Internet Explorer.

I've reviewed a number of question and answers and have a working solution but it's more like a sledge hammer in that is doubles the file size of the compiled javascript.

If I modify the entry point in `webpack.config` as below it works but this adds over 100KB of code.

```
entry: {
    main: ["babel-polyfill","./assets/src/main.js"],
}
```

Since I only require a few methods to be polyfilled I removed the polyfill from webpack and tried to modify the `babel.config` to only include those that are needed.

This is my `babel.config`

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    const presets = [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    chrome: 59,
                    edge: 11,
                    firefox: 50,
                    ie: 11,
                },
                // for uglifyjs...
                forceAllTransforms: api.env("production"),
                modules: false,
                useBuiltIns: "entry",
                "include": [
                    "es6.object.assign",
                    "es7.array.includes", //https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/data/built-in-features.js
                ]
            },
        ],
    ];
    const plugins = [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-super",
    ];
    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
}
```

However this does not work and I still experience the same Javascript error, how do I config babel to only polyfill for `Object.assign`?

I've included a partial of my Package.json with all the babel installs.

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
....
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
```

Comment: I can't test right now, but have a look at this: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#commonjs . You may be able to just import es.object.assign from there.

Comment: Thanks for now I've included `core-js/fn/object/assign` and `core-js/fn/object/assign` at the start of the entry points. Still doesn't feel that clean but much better then a 100KB of extra code. I would still prefer to get the config working above if possible.